# Force file_get_contents to read local server file from disk instead of internal cache

Tags: php, apache, caching, filesystems, cpanel

This is for a file read via a filesystem path (such as `/home/someuser/public_html/somedir/somefile.php`) – I am not talking about a file read via a URL.

I have found that (in PHP 7.1.32 at least) `file_get_contents` may return cached content rather the content now on disk, if the file has been altered by an external process (such as an FTP upload).

In the evidence trail I have, the file was updated 9 minutes previously, but `file_get_contents` nonetheless returned cached content.  The file in question was a PHP file that would have been previously read by PHP itself through `require_once` (or suchlike), though (obviously due to age) for a previous HTTP request (though would also have been ‘read’ for the current request).

EDIT/CLARIFICATION: The server process will update a file on the server, based on content of another (PHP) file, if it finds the other (PHP) file has been updated (i.e. has a more recent `filemtime`).  What was observed is that the file updated by the server process has a timestamp 9 minutes later, but has clearly been updated based on older content of the PHP file (than it currently has).

The server environment is Linux/cPanel/Apache.  OPcache is enabled for PHP.

I’ve done some research but all I could find was a [comment on the PHP documentation for `clearstatcache`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php#123405) that provides a clue but no answer:

> Note that this function affects only file metadata. However, all the PHP file system functions do their own caching of actual file contents as well. You can use the `realpath_cache_size = 0` directive in PHP.ini to disable the content caching if you like. The default content caching timeout is 120 seconds.
>
> Content caching is not a good idea during development work and for certain kinds of applications, since your code may read in old data from a file whose contents you have just changed.

**If the default content caching timeout is 120 seconds, why have I seen it cached for 9 minutes, and what is the actual setting for this in `php.ini`?**  (`realpath_cache_size` seems only to be relevant for mapping ‘relative’ paths to ‘absolute’ ones.)

**How can I disable content caching for a specific instance of a call to `file_get_contents`** (or other functions that read from files)**?**

It occurs to me that PHP might internally use its `stat` cache to determine the file hasn’t apparently been modified (even though it has) before returning the cached content for it, though that seems to me like too much caching for reliable operation.  However, the scenario is not straightforward to reproduce, and it could be wasted effort testing this hypothesis if someone already knows it would or wouldn’t be true.

**Do some of you have some more in-depth knowledge, and may be able to shed some light?**

TIA

Comment: "I have found that (in PHP 7.1.32 at least) file_get_contents may return cached content" --- it's impossible. What you observe is something else, but `file_get_contents` does not have any notion of cache and reads the file every time.

Comment: @zerkms, It's not impossible, it happened (I was surprised too), I have a clear evidence trail after several hours investigation and lots of double-checking (too much to post here, but suffice to say a file was written using apparently cached content from another file that had been updated via FTP upload 9 minutes previously).  Where the caching is happening, I can't say.  Might not be in PHP itself.  That's why I mentioned the server environment which could be relevant.  And clearly the poster on the `clearstatcache` doc page knows something...

Comment: `clearstatcache` is only about `stat` syscall results cache **within the same process only**. You need to provide some evidence, at the moment what you explained is impossible.

Comment: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.1.30/ext/standard/file.c#L520 -- see how it's implemented, no cache whatsoever

Comment: @zerkms, Hmm, maybe some kind of disk write cache from the FTP upload process or Linux itself...  Thanks for clarifying behaviour of `file_get_contents`.

Comment: From the initial heads-up, this question might now belong better on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)...

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem may be caused by preserving timestamps during FTP upload.  The file modification time on the server ends up at a (possibly significantly) older timestamp than when the file was actually changed on the server (i.e. when it was uploaded).

If a server process is using the timestamp to see if it needs to update some other file, it may determine that the file hasn't been updated when in fact it has, and thus not update the other file.  The can result in the apparent behaviour witnessed.